# How to compile a linux kernel module for different linux kernel

Tags: linux, module, linux-kernel, cross-compiling

I am sort of new to kernel programming, but i have been struggling a ton with this issue for days now. I have a machine with linux kernel '5.10.0-kali7-amd64' and im using it for development of a linux kernel module for Ubutnu 16.04.4 '4.4.0-119-generic', but i can't figure out any way that i can compile it on my machine for that version and for it to actually work on the 4.4.0 kernel machine.

The closest i've got is this:

1. I downloaded source from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+package/linux-headers-4.4.0-119
   and installed with dpkg
2. I then downloaded and installed the 4.4.0-119-generic from https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/xenial/main/updates/linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic
3. Both of them installed with no issue.
4. I compiled my module by using in my Makefile `make -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-119-generic/build M=$(PWD) modules` which also worked and compiled my hello world module.

However when uploaded to the 4.4.0 machine the insmod errored saying `insmod: ERROR: could not insert module rootkitMy.ko: Invalid module format`. The dmesg says: `module: rootkit: Unknown rela relocation: 4` I then compiled my source code on the 4.4.0 machine and created a module with literally the exact same modinfo, but that one did work.
here are the modinfos for both:

```
filename:       /rootkit.ko
version:        0.01
description:    Rootkit hook
author:         Bl4ckC4t
license:        GPL
srcversion:     46604268C8D1B7FA5115CB4
depends:        
vermagic:       4.4.0-119-generic SMP mod_unload modversions retpoline 



filename:       /rootkitMy.ko
version:        0.01
description:    Rootkit hook
author:         Bl4ckC4t
license:        GPL
srcversion:     46604268C8D1B7FA5115CB4
depends:        
vermagic:       4.4.0-119-generic SMP mod_unload modversions retpoline
```

rootkitMy.ko was compiled on the 5.10 machine and didn't work while the rootkit.ko was compiled on the 4.4.0 machine and did work properly when injected with `insmod` What can I do to compile a working module from my 5.10 machine?

Comment: Please copy and paste the complete error message into the question.

Comment: yes, sorry i added it

Comment: Please, add to the question post output of `dmesg` which is related to the `insmod` faliure.

Comment: ohhh i didn't even know that leaves output in dmesg. I will add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue. `Unknown rela relocation: 4`
is an insmod error you get due to a change in the way the kernel handles PLT, more specifically the R_X86_64_PC32 and R_X86_64_PLT32. With binutils >= 2.31, the linker has decided to use R_X86_64_PLT32 relocations, which aren't supported in the older kernel.

To fix this:

1. I downloaded an older version of binutils (2.26.1) from https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/
2. extracted the folder from the archive
3. compiled the binutils to /usr/local/binutils-2.6 by running

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/binutils-2.6
make
sudo make install
```

4. exported the new binutils to my path and recompiled my module `export PATH=/usr/local/binutils-2.6/bin:$PATH`

And now it works!